# Javascript traditional print() method style not coming in print view

Tags: javascript, css, printing

I have a print table code fiddle [LINK](http://jsfiddle.net/9DbEP/1060/)

Check my code:

```
function printData()
{
   var divToPrint=document.getElementById("printTable");
   console.log(divToPrint.outerHTML);
   newWin= window.open("");
   newWin.document.write(divToPrint.outerHTML);
   newWin.print();
   newWin.close();
}
```

I have added `background-color` to that as red as you can see in fiddle. I tried to print it. But in print the color not coming and all other things works fine. I have researched about `@media print` and all but unable to crack it. please guide me and an updated fiddle will be awesome you can give me. Cheers!

Comment: The full content of your question must be **in the question**, not just linked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Browsers tend to disable background colours and images by default.  Check your browser's printing options for a "Print background colours" option or similar, for instance in Chrome:

- In the Print dialogue, click "+ More settings" near the bottom of the left-hand column
- Tick the "Background graphics" box
- The print preview should now show you the background colour

Firefox seems to have two options under "Print Backgrounds" on the "Options" tab of the print dialogue:

- "Print Background Colours"; and
- "Print Background Images"

Note that I'm using Ubuntu; the specific wording and location of these options may vary depending on your OS as well as browser.  Some browsers may not have an option for it at all, simply stripping all background colours/images for print.

I don't think there's any way you can force these options from the JS/CSS/HTML code; it's always up to the user, along with other printing options.

Comment: Thanks buddy. So where ever I do this, need to change browser settings right?

Comment: Yes, you'll always need to check browser settings - they all do it differently, and I don't think any browser provides a way to set these options from HTML/JS/CSS.

Comment: @ NullColaShip that was awful.  don't know why they are doing this. By the way thanks a lot buddy.

Answer (score 1):

Most browsers won't print background colors or images. Some have user-controlled settings for it, but you can't count on backgrounds, it's up to the user (if the browser even lets them do it).

Separately: Your new window won't have *any* explicit styling in your example unless it's inside the `printTable` element,<sup>1</sup> as you're creating an *entirely separate window* with entirely separate content and so none of the styling of the current page is inherited.

---

<sup>1</sup> which would technically be invalid, `style` and `link` aren't allowed outside `head`, but I've never known it to actually be a problem

Comment: I have checked `console.log(divToPrint.outerHTML);` in there style is there. That is what passed to print then why it is not coming.

Comment: The Fiddle in the OP uses an inline style to achieve the background colour, so yes, it does make it into the new window.  It's then down to browser / print options.

Comment: @NullColaShip: Since that information wasn't *in the question*, I didn't assume that the styling was there.